# How to add data together from different rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table that in one column has security companies in it, another column has the id of the parent company, and the last column has that security company's market value.
I am trying to calculate the parent company's market value by adding together the market values of the security companies with the same parent id, how do I accomplish this?

The table is called security and I want the new column to be called ParentSecMktValue.

I have tried using SELECT statements:

```
SELECT security.Parent_id, security.SecMktValue
FROM security
ORDER BY Parent_id ASC;
```

This produces a table of the parent id's and their market values but I am unsure how to combine the data from the different rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the sum by using group by on parent_id and using sum function on market value

```
SELECT security.parent_id, SUM(security.SecMktValue)
FROM security GROUP BY parent_id
ORDER BY Parent_id ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.Parent_id, SUM(s.market_value) AS ParentSecMktValue
FROM security s
GROUP BY s.Parent_id
;
```